# JPA column updatable=false

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have a simple POJO (field1, field2, field3), i use Hibernate for ORM, and i have a basic need :
i should never update the field3 in DB. once a row is inserted the first time, when i call a repo to fetch an object by id (findById), even if i call the setter for field3 (setField3()), the call to save method should throw an error or an exception specifying that i am trying to update field3 and i should not.
i don't know if hibernate can handle this need or if i have to implement custom method to do that.
PS : i tried this `@Column(name = "field3", updatable = false)` and when i fetch and set another value for field3, the call to save succeeds and updates my entity.

my pojo :

```
public class Application extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ins", updatable = false)
    private String ins;
}
```

my test to reproduce the problem :

```
@Test
void updateIns_ShouldThrowError(){
    Optional<Application> parka = this.applicationRepository.findById(300L);
    assertThat(parka.isPresent());
    Application parkaApp = parka.get();
    parkaApp.setIns("ins-update");
    this.applicationRepository.save(parkaApp);
    parka = this.applicationRepository.findById(300L);
    assertThat(parka.isPresent());
    parkaApp = parka.get();
    assertThat(parkaApp.getIns()).isEqualTo("ins-update");
}
```

the test passes, i am able to update the field "ins".

Comment: Please provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository.

Comment: This is not a [MRE] and pretty much unreadable. Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE].

Comment: i edited the post, i added some code snippets that illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the setter of the field if a id is set, and throw an error if it is called.

But updatable=false should work